# A-Frame - ensuring object is in view for different browser window sizes and resolutions

Tags: camera, aframe

A-Frame newby here: I am trying to position a menu in the current view of the A-Frame camera (adding the related entities as childs of the camera entity, as suggested elsewhere as a way to create a heads-up display).
I want to position that to the top left of what the user currently sees. Therefore specifiying fixed x and y coordinates do not quite work, since the field of vision of camera depends on e.g. the screen resolution of the client the browser is running on (so on some devices the menu can be seen, on others one would have to move the camera back or turn to see the menu).
Is there a way to find out at which x,y coordinates (relative to the camera) the top left of the view is? Or another solution of how to place a menu in constant view (that works both for a classical browser window as well as in full screen and VR mode)?